# Implementing flash messages in Yii framework

Tags: php, flash, yii

This is my function from my controller :

```
public function actionUser(){
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Data1 saved!");
....
}
```

In the view If I write this :

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); ?>
```

it works, BUT I want  to appear somewhere above the content and then automatically fade out after a few second. I tried this from [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/)

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(
   'myHideEffect',
   '$(".info").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000).fadeOut("slow");',
   CClientScript::POS_READY
);
?>
```

But i don't understand who is `myHideEffect` and the class `.info` ? Can someone give me an example ? or a link to a demo?
thanks .

Comment: You have to wrap the output of the flashmessage with static content like <div class="info"><?php ... ?></div>

Comment: are you using bootstrap for your front end view if so let me know so i can share my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a jquery based question, not yii based. However try this:

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash("success")): ?>
      <div id="message">
          <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); ?>
      </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

...

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       setTimeout(function() {
           $('#message').fadeOut('slow');
       }, 3000);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: hey i tried it i am getting an jquery error. unexpected token {

Answer (score 2):

Below there are two implementation for the flash message, We can show messages using [toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) notification or the normal bootstrap flash messages implementation.

If you want display messages as toastr notification have this line of code your controller action.

```
YII::app()->user->setFlash('toastr.error', 'An Error occured when saving');
```

If you want to use the normal bootstrap flash message use instead.

```
YII::app()->user->setFlash('alert alert-danger', 'An Error occured.');
```

For this to work you have to handle the flash messages on your main view layout as below. Most likely just before  `<?php echo $content; ?>`

```
    /** Takes care of the flashmessages **/
    $flashMessages = Yii::app()->user->getFlashes();
    if ($flashMessages) {

        foreach ($flashMessages as $key => $message) {
          $pattern = '/\s/';
            $match = preg_match($pattern, $key);/* This checks the type of error message to use if the error $key is just one word then use toastr notification */
            if ($match == 0) {
                Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(
                        'myNotifyEffect', $key . '("' . $message . '");', CClientScript::POS_READY
                );
            } elseif ($match > 0) {

                if ($key != 'alert alert') {
                    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(
                            'myHideEffect', '$(".' . $key . '").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).fadeOut("slow");', CClientScript::POS_READY
                    );
                    echo '<div class= "' . $key . ' alert-bold-border square fade in alert-dismissable">' . '<button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">×</button>' . $message . "</div>\n";
                } else {
                    echo '<div class="' . $key . ' alert-bold-border square fade in alert-dismissable">' . '<button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">×</button>' . $message . "</div>\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```